# Define models in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to create a simple app!

I basically want to create something like StackOverflow, I have many `User` and many `Question`. I don't know how I should define the relationship between these two Models.

My Requirements:

- I want each `Question` to have a single author `User`, and a list of `User` that followed the `Question`.
- I want each `User` to have a list of posted `Question` and a list of followed `Question`.

I'm pretty much lost, and I don't know how to define my relationship. Is this a many-to-many relationship? If so, how do I have like 2 lists of `Question` in my `User` model (Posted/Followed)?

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, I would recommend breaking down each individual relationship. Your relationships seem to be:

1. Authoring
2. Following

For authoring, the details are:

- Each Question is authored by one User
- Each User can author many questions

As such, this is a One-to-Many relationship between the two. The best way to do this is a foreign key from the Question to the User, since there can only be one author.

For following, the details are:

- Each Question can have many following Users
- Each User can be following many Questions

As such, this is a Many-to-Many relationship. The Many-to-Many field in Django is a perfect candidate for this. Django will let you use a field through another model, but in this case this is not needed, as you have no other information associated with the fact that a user is following a question (e.g. a personal score/ranking).

With both of these relationships, Django will create lists of related items for you, so you do not have to worry about that. You may need to define a `related_name` for this field, as there are multiple users associated with a question, and by default django would make the related set for both named `user_set`.

Comment: So basically, I would have `Question` with a foreign key to `User` and with a ManyToManyField with User?

Comment: @user3772883 Yes, that is what I would recommend as well.

Comment: Something like this, in `Question`:

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    userfollowed = models.ManyToManyField(User)

Comment: yes, though you will probably need to use `related_name` in your Many-to-Many field for django not to yell at you about it. though if you can run syncdb without it, then youre fine without it

Answer (score 1):

A very basic model to get you started:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Following(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: I'd recommend to drop the `Following` model, and define a `ManyToManyField` to the `User` model. This allows for many convenience methods, such as `Question.followers.add(user)`. You can read more in the [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) topic in the documentation.